# Can't create shadow copy in command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, shadow-copy

Hopefully someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to create a shadow copy from command line so I started one with administrative rights and enter this command:

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=e:
```

But everything I get is `error: invalid command`.

When I run `vssadmin` without parameters then I am given a list of available commands, but `create` is not in the list.

Why can't I create a shadow copy?

Btw: I'm using Windows 10 Pro (x64)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

VSSAdmin only has the `create` option on Windows Server as shown [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788055(v=ws.11).aspx). Instead, you will have to make use of a PowerShell script to create the shadow.

```
powershell.exe -Command (gwmi -list win32_shadowcopy).Create('E:\','ClientAccessible')
```

Since this just makes use of the `Win32_ShadowCopy` class in WMI, you can use other methods to create the shadow. This includes the `wmic` utility.

```
wmic shadowcopy call create Volume='E:\'
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I need. Regrettably I get an error that the initialization failed. There must be something wrong on my system. :/

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I did not start the command line with administrative rights. Works like a charm! :)

Comment: +AlexS I made the same mistake, I feel pretty stupid now.. :D

Comment: Why there is this limitations? Is it exactly the same to use that script?

Comment: wmic shadowcopy can't run in parallel, so if you create multi task schedules with this command, for backup multi volumes at the same time, you will just get one success.

Comment: Works well, thanks. Are other operations, e.g. listing, removing, or restoring snapshots, possible through PowerShell, too?